# What makes two songs (parts) sound similar?

Tags: similar-artists

So, I was rehearing Wall of Voodoo since ages and thought, "Wait, the beginning of the refrain of 'Mona'..." [at 2:05](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDpgib4Gn98)

Bingo. [Start of Bazzooka "Geh ab"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt-ZmVlGLnE)

Note these are four, maximally five similar notes played on a completely different instrument! It gets worse:

[Start of "Autobahn" by Abwärts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XH9zYHtPi8) vs.
[Start of "View from a Bridge" by Kim Wilde](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APbaO8_b4Sw)

This must be the only sentence ever naming Abwärts and Kim Wilde in the same sentence, and the notes are hardly matching at all, but those eerie intros...

You don't even need notes in a strict sense - "It's Tricky" [clearly has lifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Tricky) from "Hey Mickey" (the rhyme alone was enough to know). Now that one is a "canonical" example, though, and I wonder if I'm just constantly "hearing things", due to a somewhat eclectic taste coupled with a super memory for melodies.

Do you know of any scientific studies researching how much matching is needed to throw a "similar" flag (which surely depends on the subject)? And how much similarity lets you win a lawsuit?